# Probability a pair of pairs of subvectors have the same vector sum

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume $n \geq 3$ and consider a uniformly selected random vector $V_n$ of length $2n-1$ whose elements come from $\{0,1\}$.  Also consider all $n$ of the consecutively indexed subvectors of $V$ of length $n$.  I am interested in the probability that there is a (non-identically indexed) pair of (non-identically indexed) pairs of subvectors of $V$ that have the same vector sum. Addition of vectors is simply element-wise and over the integers.

To avoid confusion, if $r_i$ is subvector $i$ then I want $i,j,k,\ell$ such that $r_i+r_j = r_k+r_{\ell}$ with rule 1)  that  we can't have both $i\in \{k,\ell\}$ and $j\in \{k,\ell\}$ and rule 2) that both $i \ne j$ and  $k \ne \ell$ hold.

Is it possible to find an upper bound for this probability? My naive guess is that ${n \choose 2}2^{-n}$ is such an upper bound and in fact numerically it seems close.

For $n=3$ there are $8$ such vectors as it is simply all those vectors that have two identical subvectors of length $3$. Those are

$(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1).$

For $n=4$ there are $32$ such vectors. Those are

$(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1).$

$p_3 = 8/32, p_4 = 32/128, p_5 = 104/512, p_6 = 328/2048, p_7 = 984/8192$.

If we ignored the overlaps and simply considered the same problem with $n$ independent vectors of length $n$ then this [Probability a pair of pairs of rows have the same vector sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639116/probability-a-pair-of-pairs-of-rows-have-the-same-vector-sum) has an answer.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble understanding exactly what you mean. How exactly do (0,0,1,0,0) and (1,1,0,1,1) work? Which pair of pairs of subvectors works?

Comment: I do get 8 vectors though, including (1,0,0,0,0), and (0,1,1,1,1) instead of the two in my comment above. If I'm confused, please enlighten me :)

Comment: @jgon Thanks. I fixed the examples for $n=3$. I'll add more when I can later on.

Comment: Cool, I'm working on the problem, but I don't know if I'll get anywhere

Comment: Are you sure about $p_7$?  My program gives $960 / 8192$.

Comment: And $p_6$; for the numerator of $p_6$ I get $324$.

Comment: The best I can do so far is $p_n \le \left[ {n \choose 2} + 3{n \choose 4} \right] 2^{-n}$.  It's a vast overestimate, but it's something.

Comment: @Goos http://paste.ubuntu.com/6810134/ has the list of 328 binary vectors I get for p_6.  I have written them as binary numbers but can write them another way if that is helpful.  Could you compare this to your list?

Comment: Fixed a bug in my program and it now agrees with $328$ and $984$.  Therefore, I've rolled back to the revision including $p_6$ and $p_7$.  (In case you're curious, my program took four indices $i < j < k < l$, and then checked if (a) $r_i + r_j = r_k + r_l$, (b) $r_i + r_k = r_j + r_l$, or (c) $r_i + r_l = r_j + r_k$.  I accidentally checked (b) twice and never checked (c).  The missing vectors in my list were all the examples of case (c).)

Comment: The vectors I was missing were: 01001101110, 01110110010, 10001001101, 10110010001.

Comment: I'm currently writing up an answer explaining my bound, and how it can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P(n)$ be the number of distinct vectors of length $2n-1$ with a pair of vector pairs with equal sum (technicalities specified in the question).
Then $p_n = P(n) / 2^{2n - 1}$.
The problem amounts to finding an upper bound on $P(n)$.

---

**Definitions**

For a fixed $n$, define functions $r_1, r_2, r_3, \ldots, r_n : \{0,1\}^{2n-1} \to \{0,1\}^n$ so that
$r_i$ extracts the $i$th subvector of a vector.
For example, if $v = 00101$, then $r_1(v) = 001, r_2(v) = 010,$ and $r_3(v) = 101$.

---

**Basic Idea**

For every vector $v$ counted by $P(n)$, at least one of the following holds:

A. $r_i(v) = r_j(v)$ for some $1 \le i < j \le n$, or

B. $r_i(v) + r_j(v) = r_k(v) + r_l(v)$ for some *4 distinct* integers $1 \le i,j,k,l \le n$.

Therefore, for any $i < j$, define $A(i,j)$ to be the number of distinct vectors $v$ such that $r_i(v) = r_j(v)$.
Similarly, for any $i, j, k, l$ distinct, define $B(i,j;k,l)$ to be the number of distinct vectors $v$ such that
$r_i(v) + r_j(v) = r_k(v) + r_l(v)$.
It is then clear that, by a large overcount

$$
P(n) \le \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} A(i,j) + \sum_{1 \le i < j < k < l\le n} \left[ B(i,j;k,l) + B(i,k;j,l) + B(i,l;j,k) \right]
\tag{*}
$$

Then, we compute:

- $\underline{A(i,j) = 2^{n-1} \text{ for } i < j}$

  Consider the $n-1$ slots in a vector $v$ that are not taken up by the subvector $r_j(v)$.
  There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to put $0$s and $1$s in these slots.
  Once the $0$s and $1$s are chosen, there is one and only way to fill in $r_j(v)$ so that $r_i(v) = r_j(v)$
  -- each entry in $r_j(v)$ must be equal to the entry $j-i$ slots before it in $v$, so we fill them in one at a time from left to right uniquely.
- $\underline{B(i,j;k,l) \le 2^{n-1} \text{ for any distinct } 1 \le i, j, k, l \le n}$

  The $i, j, k, l$ can be in any order, but we can assume without loss of generality that $l$ is bigger than the others.
  Then consider the $n-1$ slots in a vector $v$ that are not taken up by $r_l(v)$.
  There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to put $0$s and $1$s in these slots.
  But once these are filled in, the entries of $r_l(v)$, from left to right, are one by one determined by addition and subtraction of previous entries, since we need $r_l(v) = r_j(v) + r_i(v) - r_k(v)$.
  So there are at most $2^{n-1}$ vectors that work.
  Note that in this case we have overcounted, because it is not guarenteed that the addition and subtraction of previous entries will yield
  $0$ or $1$.

Now substituting this into (*), we get
\begin{align*}
P(n) &\le
\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} A(i,j) + \sum_{1 \le i < j < k < l\le n} \left[ B(i,j;k,l) + B(i,k;j,l) + B(i,l;j,k) \right]
\\ &\le
\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} 2^{n-1} + \sum_{1 \le i < j < k < l\le n} 3 \cdot 2^{n-1}
\\ &=
{n \choose 2} 2^{n-1} + {n \choose 4} 3 \cdot 2^{n-1}
\\ &=
2^{n-1} \left[ {n \choose 2} + 3{n \choose 4} \right].
\end{align*}

---

**Refinements**

There's a lot of directions you can take, but refining this bound is surprisingly tricky.  Note that we overcounted in several ways:

1. Functions $A$ and $B$ could overlap counting the same vectors.  This probably isn't a huge deal.
2. The summation of $A(i,j)$ counts a given vector $v$ not just once, but once for every pair of equal subvectors it has.
3. The summation of $B(i,j;k,l)$ and the other two $B$ terms counts a given vector $v$ not just once, but once for every
   pair of subvector pairs with equal sums.
4. Finally, we did not compute $B(i,j;k,l)$ explicitly, but gave an upper bound.
   In fact, the upper bound we gave was exactly equal to what we would get if vector addition were taken modulo $2$.
   (We required only that $r_i(v) + r_j(v) = r_k(v) + r_l(v)$ matched up in parity.)

To try and decide which of these overcounts would be best to improve upon, I made a program to compute various things.
Here is a table of some of the results.
For short, $\sum A = \sum_{i < j} A(i,j)$ and
$\sum B = \sum_{i < j < k < l} B(i,j;k,l) + B(i,k;j,l) + B(i,l;j,k)$.

\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
n & P(n) &
\sum A & \sum B &
\sum A + \sum B & 2^{n-1} \left[ {n \choose 2} + 3{n \choose 4} \right]
& A,B \text{ overlap} \\
\hline
1  & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0      & 0    \\
2  & 0     & 2     & 0     & 2     & 2      & 0    \\
3  & 8     & 12    & 0     & 12    & 12     & 0    \\
4  & 32    & 48    & 14    & 62    & 72     & 4    \\
5  & 104   & 160   & 100   & 260   & 400    & 22   \\
6  & 328   & 480   & 466   & 946   & 1920   & 70   \\
7  & 984   & 1344  & 1768  & 3112  & 8064   & 220  \\
8  & 2794  & 3584  & 5772  & 9356  & 30464  & 612  \\
9  & 7368  & 9216  & 16934 & 26150 & 105984 & 1678 \\
10 & 18632 & 23040 & 46636 & 69676 & 345600 & 4314 \\
\hline
\end{array}

(The Overlap column counts the number of vectors where $A$ and $B$ both come out positive, i.e. where there is an equal pair of subvectors
and a pair of pair of subvectors with equal sum.)

The table shows that the largest disparity is between $\sum A + \sum B$ and
our upper bound for $\sum A + \sum B$, that is, (4) in the list of ways we overcounted.
In other words, by not requiring that $r_i(v) + r_j(v) = r_k(v) + r_l(v)$ strictly, and by only requiring this modulo $2$,
we are getting a whole lot of extra vectors.
Unfortunately, this particular part of the bound is the one I am having the most difficulty improving.
Trying to make any statement about when the sum will be exactly equal proves difficult.

Disregarding this largest disparity, we can certainly work towards removing the disparities arising from (1), (2), and (3).
In particular, a complicated form of inclusion-exclusion can be used to subtract off the things we counted twice.
For example, if $v$ contained *three* equal subvectors, $A(i,j)$ counted it three times, so we should subtract $2 \sum A(i,j,k)$, where
$A(i,j,k)$ denotes the number of vectors $v$ with $r_i(v) = r_j(v) = r_k(v)$.
Similarly for $B$.
The inclusion-exclusion gets pretty complicated, and the more subvector conditions you have the harder it is to get an elegant count on it like I did above.
However, I do have several ideas for this approach, and I will come back to this answer later in the coming few weeks if these ideas get anywhere.

---

It's worth mentioning one other thing.
If I take four random vectors of length $n$, the probability that the sum of the first two equals the sum of the last two is
$(3/8)^n$ (each of the $n$ entries can be 00;00, 01;01, 01;10, 10;01, 10;10, or 11;11, which is $6/16 = 3/8$).
Thus, we might expect $r_i(v) + r_j(v) = r_k(v) + r_l(v)$ with approximately this probability.
There are ${{n \choose 2} \choose 2} = 3 {n + 1 \choose 4}$ ways to pick two distinct vector pairs,
so this would make
$$
P(n) \approx
2^{2n-1} \left( 1 - \left[(1 - (3/8)^n)^{3 {n + 1 \choose 4}}\right] \right)
$$

As it turns out, assuming I didn't make silly errors,

\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
\hline
n
& P(n)
& \approx \text{ formula above} \\
\hline
1  & 0     & 0.0     \\
2  & 0     & 0.0     \\
3  & 8     & 4.8     \\
4  & 32    & 33.1    \\
5  & 104   & 145.7   \\
6  & 328   & 519.2   \\
7  & 984   & 1611.9  \\
8  & 2794  & 4503.6  \\
9  & 7368  & 11567.9 \\
10 & 18632 & 27781.8 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So the subvectors of a $2n-1$ length vector seem to have an equal pair of subvector pair sums somewhat less often than we would expect in a random case.

---

*Minor Edit 2014-02-01:* previously I had $P(2) = 2$, due to the fact that $111$ and $000$ have a pair of equal subvectors (this was a result of the way my program worked).  I have now updated this to $P(2) = 0$ since there aren't actually any pairs of subvector pairs as specified in the question.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think there is any way of proving your observation that subvectors of a $2n-1$ length vector have an equal pair of subvector pair sums less often than we would expect in a random case? I mean to do this directly without actually giving an explicit upper bound.